# When mapping an array how do I take the difference between two years

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, mapping

So I have an array with presidents information that looks like this

```
         var presidentsLookLikeThis = [{
            "id": 1,
            "president": 1,
            "nm": "George Washington",
            "pp": "None, Federalist",
            "tm": "1789-1797"
        }];
```

and I am trying to get it to look like the one below

```
        var target = [{
            "id": 1,
            "number": 1,
            "firstName": "",
            "lastName": "", // You can include Middle Initials here
            "party": "...",
            "yearsInOffice": 4
        }];
```

so I have mapped it out below but I can't seem to figure out how to display the actual length of their presidency below. the way I have it set up now under "yearsInOffice" I am getting Undefined. would that be something I write another separate function for and then figure it out that way?

```
        var newPresidents = presidents.map(mapPresidents);

        function mapPresidents(oldPresidentsArray) {

            let namesInArray = oldPresidentsArray.nm;
            const nameParts = namesInArray.split(/ (.+)/); // incase of president having middle initial

        var newPresidentsArray = {
                id: oldPresidentsArray.id,
                number: oldPresidentsArray.president,
                firstName: nameParts[0],
                lastName: nameParts[1],   
                party: oldPresidentsArray.pp,
                yearsInOffice: oldPresidentsArray.time
            };

            return newPresidentsArray;


        };
```

thankyou in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Answer

Let's start with the confusing name of a parameter. `oldPresidentsArray` is actually an object, not an array.

Answer to your question is that on this object there is no such property as `time`. There is only `tm` and it returns a string with a range of years.

You are missing the implementation of your counting time in `mapPresidents()` function.

## Example solution

```js
var presidents = [{
            "id": 1,
            "president": 1,
            "nm": "George Washington",
            "pp": "None, Federalist",
            "tm": "1789-1797"
        }];
 
var newPresidents = presidents.map(mapPresidents);
console.log(newPresidents)

 
 function mapPresidents(oldPresident) {

            let namesInArray = oldPresident.nm;
            const nameParts = namesInArray.split(/ (.+)/); // incase of president having middle initial
            const yearsInOfficeArr = oldPresident.tm.split('-').map(year => +year) //Separate years and parse it into numbers
            const yearsInOffice = yearsInOfficeArr[1] - yearsInOfficeArr[0] || yearsInOfficeArr[0]
        var newPresident = {
                id: oldPresident.id,
                number: oldPresident.president,
                firstName: nameParts[0],
                lastName: nameParts[1],   
                party: oldPresident.pp,
                yearsInOffice: yearsInOffice
            };

            return newPresident;

        };
```

Comment: I change the name of the parameters! thanks. I changed the property as well, I had those mixed up, so yeah it is returning the string with the range of years, how would I do the implementation of counting the time you are talking about? I guess the thing I have an issue is that I need the string to be a number so I can do the math for the years?

Comment: `map(year => +year)` changes strings into numbers. It's a hacky way. You can always use `map(year => parseInt(year, 10))` Second parameter is a `radix` - defines what type of number you are expecting.

Comment: `"1789-1797".split('-').map(e=>+e)` - what is this neat trick called (`+e`)?!

Comment: const yearsInOffice = yearsInOfficeArr[1] - yearsInOfficeArr[0] || yearsInOfficeArr[0] - That should work. When there will be no `-` in a string that we split there will be only one element of an array. Means `yearsInOfficeArr[1]` is `undefined`. `||` while defining variable checkes if the 1st value is falsy (undefined, null, false, 0 etc.). In this case it is so it just takes the value after `||`

Comment: @stefanowiczp ohhh okay, I will have to read a bit into the radix. do you usually set it to 10 as default?

Comment: If you want it to be the number that most people use on a daily basis (decimal) then yes. There are other types of numbers computers use. For example hexadecimal (16 as param) that you may know from CSS color palet.